# Facebook Open Graph Protocol & App ID

Tags: facebook

I use the Facebook Open Graph protocol meta tags on my webpages with an app_id, but I can't see my pages stats in my /insights/ section on Facebook.
I'm looking for a way to see all my pages stats for a domain.

Do you know what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this tool in order to find any mistakes you could have in your metas

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint

Answer (score 0):

It's also worth noting that insights stats are (or were) only updated every 24 hours or so; hence test results from today probably won't show up until tomorrow or the day after!